# returning bool value into C- environment

Tags: c++

Say I have a function pointer in C- library

```
int (*fptr)(void);
```

And I have a class in c++

```
class A { static int func(); }
```

I can do following and it will be safe on any platform

```
ftpr = A::func;
```

I would like for `A::func()` to return `bool`.

```
class A { static bool func(); }
```

and I do not mind casting

```
fptr = reinterpret_cast<int(*)()>(A::func);
```

But will it be safe on any platform? At the first glance it seems like it will (as long as `sizeof(bool) <= sizeof(int)`) but I am not so sure.

Comment: Note http fomatting ate type from reinterpret_cast

Comment: FYI:  You can indent code by four spaces to have it formatted as code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, casting the function pointer is not safe.  Calling a function via a function pointer of the wrong type yields undefined behavior.

If you need your C++ code to interoperate with C code, do not use the C++ `bool` type (or, for that matter, any other C++ types that C does not have) in your interface.

Comment: Thanks for definitive answer: I will either push int as return values to client code or will write a light weitght c++ wrapper.

Comment: Also, make sure that any function called from C has the correct calling convention: even when calling through a pointer the function has to be declared as extern "C" (the typedef, too). Members, including static members, can't be extern "C".

Comment: @dietmar can you substantiate your opinion? My understanding is that extern "C" does not have any effect beyond name mangling (I am not using third party libraries, more over all the code in question (boht c and c++) will be compiled by the same compiler as a part of a common build.

Comment: @zzz777: I'd think this would be question on its own (although maybe with a different formulation). However, here we go: C++2011, 5.2.2 [expr.call] paragraph 1, sentence 3: "Calling a function through an expression whose function type has a language linkage that is different from the language linkage of the function type of the called function’s definition is undefined (7.5)." There are numerous implications of the `extern "C"` declaration, e.g. function can't overload, function and variable names need to be different, etc. Mangling? Not specified by the standard.

Comment: @zzz777: Also this wasn't an "opinion"! It was a **statment** :-)

Comment: @Dietmar - I am not using C++2011 and I believe a ton of code will be broken if this statement will be applicable to extern "C" definitions. However, I found relatively inexpensive way to follow your advice and will use, thank you.

Comment: @zzz777: the requirement isn't new in C++2011. It was part of C1998 but I don't have this document as readily accessible as the latest standard. ... and, yes, there is a lot of code which is broken in this respect and, yes, I needed to fix the linkage for some of my code.